# meteor js how to create rest api to regsiter user using Accounts.createUser?

Tags: meteor

I have created web app in meteor js and now i need to create api's for mobile native app . My app is using this route for login on web app. 
Path of web app login route

*myapp\myappv1\app\lib\routes.js*

```
Router.route('login', {
  name: 'login',
  controller: 'LoginController',
  where: 'client'
});
```

And to create api I have created *server.js* file in _myapp\myappv1\app\server_ directory and I'm trying to create api to register a user.

```
Router.route('/register/',{where: 'server'})

 .post(function(){
//console.log(this.request.body);
//return false;
let user = { 
email : this.request.body.email,
username : this.request.body.username,
password : this.request.body.password,
countrycode : this.request.body.countrycode,
mobileno : this.request.body.mobileno,
};

});
   Meteor.call('registerForm', user, function(error, response1) {
        if (error) {
             response = {
                            "error" : true,
                            "message" : error,
                        }
        }
        if (response1) {
            response = {
                            "error" : false,
                            "UserID" : response1,
                        }
        }
    });
    this.response.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    this.response.end(JSON.stringify(response));
   });
```

It's showing error in callback. How I can get response with `Accounts.createUser`. It's inserting data into database but 
in response returns error "Accounts.createUser with callback not supported on the server".

Comment: Routes using a Router in Meteor are still DDP based. To create REST routes you may check out the wabapp package: https://docs.meteor.com/packages/webapp.html

Comment: so it's not right way to create api ?

Comment: also at web app end i am using Accounts.createUser to create a user and if a user will be regsiter from mobile app using api then records should be added same as inserting from web app using Accounts.createUser.

Comment: now i have created a method  Meteor.call('registerForm', user, function(error, response1) {  });  in methods and call it in api. Is this right approch?